# Autofac life time error on windows 2012 server IIS 8.5

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have a problem with Autofac on IIS 8.5 and windows server, I have to say everything is OK on development environment and testing are going fine but on production server I'm getting this error:

> "An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = MessagesController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Pharmacy.Api.Controllers.MessagesController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = NotificationHandler (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Pharmacy.Api.Handlers.INotificationHandler], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Pharmacy.Services.INotificationClientService)' on type 'NotificationHandler'. ---> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: input (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

I tested different type of Autofac configs at application start:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<NotificationHandler>()
                                    .As<INotificationHandler>()
                                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<NotificationHandler>()
                                .As<INotificationHandler>()
                                .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(NotificationHandler).Assembly)
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .InstancePerRequest();

var container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

and my controller is like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private readonly INotificationHandler _notificationHnadler;
    public TestController(INotificationHandler notificationHnadler)
    {
        _notificationHnadler = notificationHnadler;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestNotification()
    {
       //doing something
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't even enough info here to guess what is happening. But it probably has something to do with something in your startup path that is different between production and dev (your non-scanning registration code isn't it).

Comment: @NightOwl888 its really simple configuration there is no more things. if you need other info just ask

Comment: What I am saying is that the code you have posted obviously isn't causing the problem. So, please post more of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), particularly the startup code that sets it into motion.

Comment: Please update your question and show the `NotificationHandler` class including its constructor. My best bet is that you 1. specified the `INotificationClientService` constructor argument of `NotificationHandler` as **optional** and 2. Didn't register `INotificationClientService` in the container.

Comment: Looks like the class that implements `INotificationClientService` is not   in the same assembly than `NotificationHandler`, that would explain why it doesn't get registered with that  `RegisterAssemblyTypes`. You should register it explicitly. As other comments say, it is difficult to know without seeing the code of `INotificationClientService` or `NotificationHandler`, or knowing which classes implement that interface.